# Modal Dialog from a Modal Dialog - both close when second is closed - why?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, modal-dialog

C# / .NET 3.5 / WinForms

I've got a form that opens a modal dialog form which opens another modal dialog form.  The inner dialog form has OK and Cancel buttons and its AcceptButton and CancelButton are set to them respectively.

When I hit Enter or click OK in the inner dialog, the outer dialog closes as well.  I can't see where I'm doing this - is this expected behaviour?

I can supply code but I didn't want to clutter this up.

Comment: Is the outer dialog running modally [via .ShowDialog] ? You should be able to place a breakpoint after the call in a debugger. But I guess you wouldnt have asked if there wasnt some subtlety to what you're doing...

Comment: Yeah, I'd stepped through the code but it just popped from the inner to the outer without hitting anything.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This happens because a `ShowDialog` call modifies its owner's state as well.

To prevent this from happening, you need to reset the `DialogResult` of the first modal dialog to `DialogResult.None` after the `ShowDialog` call to the second dialog:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    InnerDialog inner = new InnerDialog()
    DialogResult innerResult = inner.ShowDialog(this);
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.None;
}
```

This has been a long-standing issue (see [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/cumgranosalis/archive/2005/10/03/ShowDialog-in-ShowDialog.aspx) post).

Comment: That's it.  I had a feeling I'd hit this one before a long time ago but I couldn't find it and Google didn't help.  Problem solved.  Thanks very much.

Comment: Maybe this is fixed? I have .Net 3.5 SP1 and do *NOT* see this behavior.

Comment: Possibly so. I've just tried it on .Net 3.5 SP1 and didn't get the behaviour. I've definitely had it on .Net 2.0 though.

Comment: It's even not fixed in .NET 4.7.2 (vb.NET)

Answer (score 0):

I have struggled with this the whole day until I found this post. It has not been fixed in .NET 4.